Why do we maximise the Lagrangian with respect to the multipliers (in Support Vector Machines)?
I've been reading about SVM's, and came across the method of solving the SVM Optimization Problem using Lagrangian multipliers to convert the constrained optimization problem into an unconstrained one.
$
L(w, b, \alpha) = \frac{1}{2} \|w\|^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \big(y_i (w \cdot x_i + b) - 1\big)
$
The process involves minimizing $L(w,b,\alpha)$ with respect to the parameters $w$ and $b$, and then maximizing the below equation (after plugging in the optimal $w$ value) with respect to the Lagrangian multipliers $\alpha_i$:
Dual Problem:
$$
\text{Maximize: } L(\alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j y_i y_j (x_i \cdot x_j), \\
\text{subject to: } \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i y_i = 0, \quad \alpha_i \geq 0 \text{ for all } i.
\
$$
My question is: if our original goal was to minimize the Lagrangian function, which we are rightly doing with respect to $w$ and $b$, why are we then maximizing it with respect to $\alpha$?
I've read in some references that it it helps in strengthening the constraints that are being applied, but it didn't make much intuitive sense to me since I'm new to Convex Optimization.
Can someone explain the purpose behind minimizing and then maximizing? Why can't we minimize both times?

The main reason is because of the concavity of the function. $L(w, b, \alpha)$ is convex w.r.t. $w$ and $b$, but $Q(\alpha)$ is concave w.r.t $\alpha$.
